# How to make loader wait specific divs

Tags: jquery, css, wait, loader

I've been using this little thing (code) for loader animations on my sites and I'd like to know is it possible to make it wait only few specific div elements before if fades out. Now it waits the whole site loads up before showing it but I'd like to make it wait only divs visible on top of the site to make it faster.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.loader').fadeOut(250);
})

<div class="loader"></div>

.loader {
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:100%;
top:0px;
left:0px;
z-index:9999;
background-color:#000;
background-image: url(images/loader.gif);
backgourd-repeat:no-repeat;
background-postition:50% 50%;
}
```

Comment: this will works for you $("your div").ready(function(){
  $('.loader').fadeOut(250);
});

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery load-event on certain div instead of calling it on entire window:

```js
$( "#your-div" ).load(function() {
  $('.loader').fadeOut(250);
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: .load() is deprecated. use `.on("load", handler)` instead

Answer (score 0):

check this out
**Snippet**

```js
  $("#wait").ready(function(){
    $('.loder').fadeOut(250);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wait"><p>this is a div</p></div>

<div class="loder">Some Content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it make a lot of sense to have a loading icon and remove it before the page is actually loaded? To the user it gives the wrong impression that the page is ready while it's still being loaded. I don't think this is advisable. As a compromise I suggest jQuery's `.ready()` method to remove the loader. The handler is executed as soon as the DOM is ready but before any more assets like images for example are loaded. http://api.jquery.com/ready/

```js
$(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
  $('.loader').remove();
});
```

```css
.loader {
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:100%;
top:0px;
left:0px;
z-index:9999;
background-color:#000;
background-image: url(images/loader.gif);
backgourd-repeat:no-repeat;
background-postition:50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="loader"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `setInterval` you can check let's say every 200 ms if the element was added to the DOM. Once is being added you then can clear the check using `clearInterval()`:

```
var checkIfExists = setInterval(function() {
  if ($('div').length) {
    $('.loader').fadeOut(250);
    clearInterval(checkIfExists);
  }
}, 200);
```